# Nrwl NX nodejs production build remove comments and minify

Tags: node.js, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Inside a Nrwl NX monorepo there's a nodejs app.

When building for production, how can this be achieved:

1. Remove comments
2. Minify the app

I don't get how webpack configuration works in the Nrwl NX namespace or how to install webpack modules like UglifyJSPlugin.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to minify/bundle a node app.
It's not like it is a frontend application where it is served to the client.
This is not usually the case for backend apps.

So by default, Nx does not do this.

If you want to do this you need to provide your own executor

```
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/js:tsc", // <-----
```

or after all the artifacts have been built when you run `nx build` you can run a secondary script which you would have to create that takes all the js files and minify/bundle etc...

Answer (score 0):

NX provides an `esbuild` executor which accepts a `minify` option.

You can use the `@nx/js:setup-build` generator to switch to `esbuild`:

```
> `npx nx generate @nx/js:setup-build --project=THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT --bundler=esbuild`
```

This will also add the `minify: true` option for you.
Your `project.json` will look like this:

```json
{
  ...
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/esbuild:esbuild",
      ...
      "options": {
        "minify": true,
        ...
      }
    }
  ...
  }
}
```